# problem while uninstalling IIS from windows XP

Tags: iis, mac, windows-xp

I want to remove or disable IIS from my computer

i tried to go to add/remove programs -> windows comonens but it dosnt work

actually i dont  know  if it is  the right way to remove it or not

bu when i try it ask me to insert windows CD

and i tried  to restart my computer and then choose the safe mode but i cant

mayb bcause i am orking on **mac hrdware** ??

any idea please ?

Comment: What happens if you insert the Windows CD?

Answer (score 0):

Add/Remove Programs, Windows Components is the correct way.

Often when reconfiguring WIndows, it will ask for the CD.  Do you have it?  What does it do when you insert it and click OK?  Do you have a directory labeled i386 on the Hard Drive,  often installers will copy this directory from the CD to make installs/reconfigs etc easier,  it probably has what windows is looking for,  so you click select browse, and navigate to i386, and give it a try.